# Can I if else 'setContentView' in java for Android app xml layouts?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gradle-plugin, mustache

I'm wondering if it is possible to load a layout based on an if/else statement in java for an Android app.

I've tried the following and the emulator keeps crashing when I initiate a load.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // The If/Else Statement in question
    if ( CompanyStatus.RECOMMENDED == company.getStatus() ) {
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_company_large );
    } else {
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_company );
    }

    setupBackButton();
    spiceManager.start( this );
    populateView();
}
```

I would expect that when `CompanyStatus.RECOMMENDED == company.getStatus()` it would load the activity_company_large layout otherwise it would load the activity company layout. But, the emulator is crashing when I initiate the if/else layout load.

Comment: Can you add the crash logs in question? It would  be very helpful to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if it is possible to load a layout based on an if/else statement in java for an Android app.

Yes, you can. But you need to make sure you're binding the correct view with `findViewById` according to the selected layout.

> I would expect that when CompanyStatus.RECOMMENDED == company.getStatus() it would load the activity_company_large layout otherwise it would load the activity company layout. But, the emulator is crashing when I initiate the if/else layout load.

The crash probably because you haven't initialize the `company` object when you trying to get the status on the following line:

```
if ( CompanyStatus.RECOMMENDED == company.getStatus() ) {

}
```

Check if it is already initialized or not.